# How to fetch parametrized values from csv which is in different row for each request for a same user

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I need to run JMeter script for 1 user. The script has 20 requests, in each request i have more than 10 different parametrized value. So i need to put values in each column so it comes around 200 columns. Is there any way i can reduce the columns or i will put it in each row and ask Jmeter to pick forst 10 rows for user 1 and next 10 rows for 2 nde user and so on.

Using separate csv's for each request will help but where we need to create 20 csvs. Is there way to use with single csv in optimized way like using loop.

Answer (score 0):

Given default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of `All Threads` each virtual user will pick next row on each iteration.

If this is something which doesn't fit your needs you can consider using [baolu-csv-data-file-config](https://github.com/LeeBaul/baolu-csv-data-file-config) plugin which provides possibility to allocate "blocks" of CSV entries to each user

[image]

The above plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

Comment: Thanks! will check the possibilities.